# Read a string with special characters and use it in `tr` and `sed`

Tags: bash, sed, tr

I have the following strings

```
$A%^]I"S-)|>J&`_@;!UVPOSM\
IV&|M
```

This contains special characters and hence `Bash` can't interpret it correctly unless quoted

The first string is just the substitution of the range `A-Z`

I tried the following

`tr` 1

```sh
read -r A
tr $A A-Z
```

`tr` 2

```sh
read -r A
tr "$A" A-Z
```

Using `sed`

```sh
read -r A
sed "y/${A}/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/"
```

```sh
read -r A
sed 'y/'$A'/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/'
```

```sh
read -r A
sed 'y/'${A}'/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/'
```

None of them worked. Also, using the options `-ps` in `read` also didn't work.

The error for `tr` is

```
tr: range-endpoints of 'S-)' are in reverse collating sequence order
```

Error for `sed`

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 56: unterminated `y' command
```

The output when the first string is translated to A-Z will give "FUNKY"

How to resolve this?

Comment: `read -r A` Wil read one line. You have two lines. `'y/'$A'/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/'
` I do not understadn - what do you want to replace. In what?

Comment: Yes. It will automatically apply the command in the second line over the next input. So, I don't have a need to read the second line

Comment: No it will not, `read` reads one line. What is "it"? `use it in tr and sed` _How_ do you want to "use" the string? `How to resolve this?` The `tr` error is correct - the string is invalid argument for `tr`. As for `sed`, replace newline with `\n`.

Comment: "It" refers to the online IDE

Comment: All the STDIN will be given at one. So, the online IDE will automatically apply the command to all the remaining lines of input

Comment: Sure - will apply "what"? What do you want to do with the input? You want to replace characters in the range `A-Z` with something else? If so, with what? `The first string is just the substitution of the range A-Z` What do you mean by "is substitution"? Does it substitute something? In what way does it replace it? Is this a Caesar cipher with custom alphabet? And - `hence Bash can't interpret it` Bash is fine, bash has only problems with zero byte, `tr` and `sed` can't interpret it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235215/discussion-between-john-brookfields-and-kamilcuk).

Comment: Substitution cipher

Comment: See this [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vyg1MUVBt0jBkaukSEHFUcFRN@r//ygf1/BQT@fAsIAI30jHIHe/YH@nEG8XDzcvrsBQX98gAA "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: So there is a first line. Each character of the first line corresponds to a character in the range `A-Z`, a mapping per se. Then on further lines, you want to replace characters from the first line to the corresponding character in the `A-Z` range?

Answer (score 3):

Special characters can be escaped with `\` for `tr` and `sed` utilities. The programs `tr` and `sed` have different special characters sets and parsing rules. However, escaping just `[` `-` and `\` seems to be just enough for both programs for the presented input.

```
IFS= read -r a;
a=$(sed 's/[[\-]/\\&/g' <<<"$a")
tr "$a" 'A-Z'
# or
sed "y/$a/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/"
```

Check your scripts with shellcheck.net . Research quoting in shell and when to use it. Research how to debug scripts and about `set -x` option. See `sed` and `tr` documentation - https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/utilities/tr.html and https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html . Prefer to use lower case variable names. Also you might be interested in https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Here_strings .

I think the best full proof way might be to convert first line and convert to octal `\NNN` numbers and then pass to `tr`. Like so:

```
IFS= read -r a;
a=$(printf "%s" "$a" | od -An -b | tr -d ' \n' | sed 's/.../\\&/g');
tr "$a" 'A-Z';
```

Comment: I don't thik `tr` needs for `[` to be escaped; conversely, the `y` command in `sed` does not recognize `-` as a range operator. (This is usually seen as a drawback, but plays nicely into our hands here.)

Answer (score 1):

Both `tr` and `sed` are *filters;* they read one or more lines from standard input, execute a transformation (which in `sed` can be a quite complex script with conditional branches and loops), and print the result to standard output.

The `y` command in `sed` is quite similar to `tr`; they both accept two lists of characters, where the *n*th character in the first list will be mapped to the *n*th character in the second.

`tr` has an additional feature where you can abbreviate a list of adjacent characters; thus `tr A-Za-z N-ZA-Mn-za-m` implements the familiar `rot13` algorithm. This explains why you got an error when you tried to pass in a string with a dash - it was interpreted as a range operator, but regarded as invalid because the range's start had a higher character code than its end.

The `sed` error comes because the backslash is interpreted as escaping the final delimiter; `\/` is how you would put a literal slash in the sbustitution or replacement string.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to map A-Z to the first line of your input, and provide the second as input to this transformation?

```sh
#!/bin/bash
exec <"$1"
IFS='' read -r A
sed "y/${A//\\/\\\\}/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/"
```

The `exec` tells Bash to read standard input from the named file; you would pass the name of your file as the argument to this script. The string substitution `${A//pattern/replacement}` takes care to double any literal backslashes in the variable's value.

It's not impossible to come up with something similar for `tr`. The main challenge is that you have to put the dash first or last, and correspondingly reorder the output mapping. Some `tr` implementations might allow you to use `---` to specify a one-character range where the middle dash is a range operator and the other two are the start and end characters of the range.